# Suddenly for one specific function of a specific object, getting NULL pointer in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, exc-bad-access

here is the code snippet

```
Obj *temp;
temp = new Sphere(center, radius);
struct color c = {1, 0, 0};
temp->setColor(c); //works fine
temp->setShine(1); //works fine
temp->setCoefficients(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2); //works fine
temp->draw(); //NULL pointer!!
objects.push_back(temp);

temp = new Floor(1000, 20);
temp->draw(); //works fine too!
objects.push_back(temp);
```

where Obj is a base class, Sphere and Floor are derived class, draw is a virtual method.

Before my draw function worked perfectly and there was no pointer issue. Suddenly I am getting this exc-bad-access error and I debugged and found out that from wherever I call Sphere::draw(), "this" pointer becomes null.

(I'm having trouble with pasting the Sphere::draw() function properly here.)

```
glPushMatrix();
{
    glColor3f(c.r, c.g, c.b);
    glTranslatef(referencePoint.x, referencePoint.y, referencePoint.z);
printf("inside sphere draw\n");
    double radius = length;
    struct point points[1000][1000];
    int stacks = 1000, slices = 1000;
    int i,j;
    double h,r;
    //generate points
    for(i=0;i<=stacks;i++)
    {
        h=radius*sin(((double)i/(double)stacks)*(pi/2));
        r=radius*cos(((double)i/(double)stacks)*(pi/2));
        for(j=0;j<=slices;j++)
        {
            points[i][j].x=r*cos(((double)j/(double)slices)*2*pi);
            points[i][j].y=r*sin(((double)j/(double)slices)*2*pi);
            points[i][j].z=h;
        }
    }
    //draw quads using generated points
    for(i=0;i<stacks;i++)
    {
        glColor3f(1.0, 0, 0);
        //glColor3f((double)i/(double)stacks,(double)i/(double)stacks,(double)i/(double)stacks);
        for(j=0;j<slices;j++)
        {
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            {
                //upper hemisphere
                glVertex3f(points[i][j].x,points[i][j].y,points[i][j].z);
                glVertex3f(points[i][j+1].x,points[i][j+1].y,points[i][j+1].z);
                glVertex3f(points[i+1][j+1].x,points[i+1][j+1].y,points[i+1][j+1].z);
                glVertex3f(points[i+1][j].x,points[i+1][j].y,points[i+1][j].z);
                //lower hemisphere
                glVertex3f(points[i][j].x,points[i][j].y,-points[i][j].z);
                glVertex3f(points[i][j+1].x,points[i][j+1].y,-points[i][j+1].z);
                glVertex3f(points[i+1][j+1].x,points[i+1][j+1].y,-points[i+1][j+1].z);
                glVertex3f(points[i+1][j].x,points[i+1][j].y,-points[i+1][j].z);
            }glEnd();
        }
    }

}glPopMatrix();
```

}

Comment: The error is in the changes that you have done before to your code. Set a watchpoint on temp in your debugger.

Comment: yes, actually I've found it a while ago. Thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

The pointer is not nullified, you just try to write something beyond the array boundaries. Here:

```
for(i=0;i<=stacks;i++)
```

here:

```
for(j=0;j<=slices;j++)
```

The last element of this array is points[stacks-1][slices-1], and in your loop condition you are trying to refer to points[stacks][slices] in the last iteration.

Also, there's another problem in these lines:

here:

```
glVertex3f(points[i][j+1].x,points[i][j+1].y,points[i][j+1].z);
glVertex3f(points[i+1][j+1].x,points[i+1][j+1].y,points[i+1][j+1].z);
glVertex3f(points[i+1][j].x,points[i+1][j].y,points[i+1][j].z);
```

and here:

```
glVertex3f(points[i][j+1].x,points[i][j+1].y,-points[i][j+1].z);
glVertex3f(points[i+1][j+1].x,points[i+1][j+1].y,-points[i+1][j+1].z);
glVertex3f(points[i+1][j].x,points[i+1][j].y,-points[i+1][j].z);
```

Those `[i+1]`, `[j+1]` parts are trying to do the same as above in the last iteration.

Comment: You're welcome. You may accept this answer if you think it has solved your problem.